# Modal Windows using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a web app where in I need to add some values inputted by the user.

When the user clicks on the Add button he sees a form and these values then show up on the page. Now to implement this I can do two things

1. Use a modal window
2. Make a form inside the page itself(in a div) and toggle its visibility by the Add button.

If I go with the former solution is it necessary to use Ajax or I can add elements on the main page directly itself? Are there any jQuery plugins to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use Ajax to accomplish this. The difference in the two methods is simply whether you use an inline block of code that is hidden and displayed later, or whether you use an absolutely-positioned block of code doing exactly the same thing.

In most cases there is a single form that envelops the entire page. The rest is a matter of a CSS and positioning.

Answer (score 2):

As Diodeus mentioned, you don't need Ajax.
In answer to your other question about the plugins, have a look at [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) for the dialog. Generating the form is pretty trivial. There's no need for a plugin there